# How can we get the query history related to user tables only?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Following query, from [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/tune-performance-with-the-query-store?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16#last-queries-executed-on-the-database), returns the text of the queries run by a user, as well as the queries run internally by sql server (for internal usage).

**Question**: How can we refine this query to return only the queries run by users (does not have to be for a specific user). Or are there any alternate queries that return only the query text for queries on user tables only?

For example, the following sql return a query test like the following. I do not want such query text. I am interested only queries involving user tables like `Select lName, fName FROM Customers` or update statements on user tables etc.:

For example following query text should not be returned since it does not involve user tables:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(xproc.schema_id) AS [Schema], xproc.name AS [Name], xproc.object_id AS [ID], CAST( xproc.is_ms_shipped AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject] FROM sys.all_objects AS xproc WHERE (xproc.type='X') ORDER BY [Schema] ASC,[Name] ASC
```

**Need the following query to return query text on user tables (not system tables)**: May be there are attribute in the `DMVs` used below that can be used in the `WHERE` clause of the code below to filter out the queries like the one above?

```
SELECT TOP 10000 qt.query_sql_text, q.query_id,
    qt.query_text_id, p.plan_id, rs.last_execution_time
FROM sys.query_store_query_text AS qt
JOIN sys.query_store_query AS q
    ON qt.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan AS p
    ON q.query_id = p.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats AS rs
    ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
ORDER BY rs.last_execution_time DESC;
```

Ref: [sys.query_store_query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [query_store_query_text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [query_store_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [query_store_runtime_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-runtime-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: What if it's a user generated query, but no table is involved at all, e.g. `SELECT 123 AS ID;`? Do you want it included in the results or not? What about a query that involves both a user table and a system table in the same query?

Comment: Also SQL Server and Azure SQL Database are two different products. Which one are you using?

Comment: @J.D. Generic queries such as `SELECT 123 AS ID` can be ignored. the idea is to investigate the usage of the queries - over an extended amount of time - to find out which queries need what indexes on what columns. Hence queries involving both system and user tables can also be ignored.

Comment: Did you read [Tune nonclustered indexes with missing index suggestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/tune-nonclustered-missing-index-suggestions?view=sql-server-ver16)